# How to trigger more than one target value simultaneously in vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, logic

I have a code that is triggered by user entry in column K and P:
If any value is inserted in "K" then offset to corresponding cell in column R and fills the username.
If any value is inserted in "P" then offset to corresponding cell in column Q and fills the data using TODAY().

My code looks like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim UserName As String
UserName = Environ("username")

    If Target.Column <> 11 Then Exit Sub
    Target.Offset(, 7).Value = IIf(Target.Value = "", "", UserName)
   
    If Target.Column <> 16 Then Exit Sub
    Target.Offset(, 1).Value = IIf(Target.Value = "", "", Now)


End Sub
```

The problem is that it is only working with the first IF, how can I get it to work with both?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test each cell in the target range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If cell.Column = 11 Then
            cell.Offset(, 7).Value = IIf(cell.Value = "", "", Environ("username"))
        ElseIf cell.Column = 16 Then
            cell.Offset(, 1).Value = IIf(cell.Value = "", "", Now)
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: `.Cells` is redundant, right?

Comment: @bigben Probably yes, just documenting the fact that target can be more than one cell

Comment: (I would think that's evident from the `For Each` loop).